# Does HylaFax server run in OS X?

Tags: osx, modem

From their [FAQ](http://www.hylafax.org/content/FAQ):

> HylaFAX is intended to run on any UNIX system that supports a particular set of features: FIFO special files, BSD-style sockets and the TCP/IP communication protocols, BSD-style file locking (`flock`) or equivalent functionality from which it can be emulated (`fcntl`, `lockf`), and POSIX 1003.1-style interfaces, including `termios` for manipulating `tty` devices.

There there is a long list of compatible operating systems, but it does not include OS X. My knowledge of OS X low-level features is limited, so I would like to ask you if OS X supports the aforementioned features

Comment: I see some some signs of it kicking around in MacPorts, but nothing recent that makes me think it would work on Leopard or Lion.